# Efficiently removing items from the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, dom

This is kind of a nitpicky question, but I'm curious which would be a more efficient implementation.

I'm adding an overlay and a spinner over an element, then later I'm removing it.

I can define two methods:

```
    addSpinner: function() {
        $('<div></div>').addClass('overlay').appendTo('#myDiv');
        $('<img>').attr('src', 'images/spinner.gif').addClass('spinner').appendTo('#myDiv');
    },

    removeSpinner: function() {
        $('.overlay, .spinner', this.el).remove();
    },
```

The remove spinner is going to have to look for those elements each time I call it. So my other option is to have `addSpinner` re-define `removeSpinner` with a more direct reference to the elements.

```
addSpinner: function() {
    var overlay = $('<div></div>').addClass('overlay').appendTo('#myDiv');
    var spinner = $('<img>').attr('src', 'images/spinner.gif').addClass('spinner').appendTo('#myDiv');
    this.removeSpinner = function() {
        overlay.remove();
        spinner.remove();
    };
},
```

This means no searching the DOM for those two elements, but the function is redefined each time.  Pros and Cons?

I don't think it's relevant but these are Backbone/Marionette views.

Comment: Why not test it?
Just run them both a couple of hundred thousand times and see which takes longer?

Comment: To test JavaScript 'efficiency' there's [jsperf.com](http://jsperf.com/). Have you tried composing a test-case to assess these approaches?

Comment: @DavidThomas Didn't know about that, thanks!  http://jsperf.com/dom-removal-efficiency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most efficient would probably be to keep a reference to the elements that you can use when you remove them, something like

```
var obj = {
    addSpinner: function() {
        this.overlay = $('<div />', {'class' : 'overlay'});
        this.spinner = $('<img />', {'class' : 'spinner', src : 'images/spinner.gif'});

        $('#myDiv').append(this.overlay, this.spinner);

    },
    removeSpinner: function() {
        this.overlay.add(this.spinner).remove();
    }
}
```

That way you don't have to call jQuery or query the DOM uneccessary

Comment: Hmmm, jsperf was annoyingly indecisive.  Here's 4 runs: http://i.imgur.com/a6if10G.jpg

You can try yourself: http://jsperf.com/dom-removal-efficiency

Comment: You're not going to get much of a difference when you have the same code in each test, try it more like this -> http://jsperf.com/dom-removal-efficiency/2

Comment: @adeneo Oh, I was under the impression that I only wanted to test the execution time of the functions.  The way you have it set up, aren't the functions being redefined every time the test is run?